# Git reflog graph?

Tags: git

Is there any way to show a git log graph with reflog references like `mybranch@{N}`? This would be useful after doing a rebase to see the previous and current versions of the branch in a graph. Basically what I want (I think) is `git log --graph --walk-reflogs mybranch` but that gives me an error `fatal: cannot combine --walk-reflogs with history-limiting options`.

I can get very close with `git log --graph --reflog mybranch` but that does not show reflog references like `mybranch@{1}`.

Maybe this is a limitation since you can't walk the ancestry and the reflog in the same command? Still, it seems like there should be a way to walk the reflog 5 entries or so and feed those references with labels to `git log --graph`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Maybe this is a limitation since you can't walk the ancestry and the reflog in the same command?

That's exactly right.

The main issue here is that Git can only add these label-decorators (`%d` for normal decorations, or `%gD` for reflog selector decorations) to commits if it can *find* the decorator.  To allow the `%d` decorators to work, Git *always* reads all branch and tag and other reference names.  But for `%gD` to work, Git must read the reflog entries, and unless you use `--walk-reflogs` (or `-g` for short), it doesn't read the reflog entries at all.  Once you *do* use `-g`, it does read the reflogs, but stops walking the commit graph.

There's no fundamental reason Git couldn't read all reflogs if and when `%gD` appeared in the formatting directives, so that it could add those decorators, but it doesn't today.

There's a separate, but equally important, problem that occurs if and when you solve this first one: `--graph` cannot be combined with `--no-walk` and `--walk-reflogs` implies `--no-walk` (they're separate internal walk functions and the graph-generating code depends heavily on using the history walker, not the reflog walker).

(The best you can do with current Git is parse the output from `git log`, while also reading all the reflog values yourself.  You can then write your own code to add reflog labels.)

Comment: But is there not the additional problem that branches can be added and deleted while commits are always well defined?

Comment: @Christoph: it's true that you can add or delete branch names at any time. This just changes the set of decorations available for the commits, or—in some cases when you delete names—makes some commit hash IDs un-find-able (after which they're eventually garbage collected).

Comment: Bit weird that git log couldn't /also/ walk reflog, and just attach the extra labels to branches/commits that match, and also add orphans. It might make for a messy display, but could be useful.